# how to retrive all CNContactStore from device without filter

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact

I'm trying to insert into `var contacts: [CNContact] = []`
the `var store = CNContactStore()` but I did not find the right code for this job, i found this function that I need to give that a name

```
func findContactsWithName(name: String) {
    AppDelegate.sharedDelegate().checkAccessStatus({ (accessGranted) -> Void in
        if accessGranted {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                do {
                    let predicate: NSPredicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsMatchingName(name)
                    let keysToFetch = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactBirthdayKey, CNContactViewController.descriptorForRequiredKeys()]
                    self.contacts = try self.store.unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate(predicate, keysToFetch:keysToFetch)


                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
                catch {
                    print("Unable to refetch the selected contact.")
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

I want to insert `self.contacts` all the records and not only one with name equal

Comment: Hi the below line of code will gives given name, family name, birthday.                ** let keysToFetch = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactBirthdayKey, CNContactViewController.descriptorForRequiredKeys()]**                                     If i want to retrieve all the details of a contact how to fetch ?.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update**

Based on comment from OP, please try the following CNContactFetchRequest-based API to retrieve all contacts without a filter. I run this on a background thread to reduce any possible issues huge numbers of contacts.

```
func findContactsOnBackgroundThread ( completionHandler:(contacts:[CNContact]?)->()) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0), { () -> Void in

            let keysToFetch = [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle(.FullName),CNContactPhoneNumbersKey] //CNContactIdentifierKey
            let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest( keysToFetch: keysToFetch)
            var contacts = [CNContact]()
            CNContact.localizedStringForKey(CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone)

            fetchRequest.mutableObjects = false
            fetchRequest.unifyResults = true
            fetchRequest.sortOrder = .UserDefault

            let contactStoreID = CNContactStore().defaultContainerIdentifier()
            print("\(contactStoreID)")


            do {

                try CNContactStore().enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(fetchRequest) { (contact, stop) -> Void in
                    //do something with contact
                    if contact.phoneNumbers.count > 0 {
                        contacts.append(contact)
                    }

                }
            } catch let e as NSError {
                print(e.localizedDescription)
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                completionHandler(contacts: contacts)

            })
        })
    }
```

Generally speaking you would normally set a predicate to nil to retrieve all of the contacts when using [CNContactFetchRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNContactFetchRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CNContactFetchRequest/predicate) class rather than as described in your code.

**Note**

If you want to use your existing API then I recommend setting the predicate to true:

```
 NSPredicate(value: true)
```

This should make all contacts return.  If that does not work consider switching to the CNConctactFetchRequest API to enumerate the Contacts. In that event you could then set the predicate to nil to fetch all contacts (using CNConctactFetchRequest).

[image: CNContactFetch-Predicate]

This is how you might modify the existing method:

```
func findContacts()->[CNContact] {
        AppDelegate.sharedDelegate().checkAccessStatus({ (accessGranted) -> Void in
            if accessGranted {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    do {
                        let predicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
                        let keysToFetch = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactBirthdayKey, CNContactViewController.descriptorForRequiredKeys()]
                        self.contacts = try self.store.unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate(predicate, keysToFetch:keysToFetch)


                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                    catch {
                        print("Unable to refetch the selected contact.")
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

And to use:

```
let contacts = findContacts()
```

Apple has a simpler sample:

```
let store = CNContactStore()
let contacts = try store.unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate(CNContact.predicateForContactsMatchingName("Appleseed"), keysToFetch:[CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey])
```

**For your use-case, you could try to modify the Apple Sample like this:**

```
//Use the reference to look up additional keys constants that you may want to fetch
let store = CNContactStore()
let contacts = try store.unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate(NSPredicate(value: true), keysToFetch:[CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey])
```

[More Apple Samples for the Contacts Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015328)

Comment: I'm geting Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CNInvalidPredicateException', reason: 'The predicate TRUEPREDICATE is not a valid Contact predicat

Comment: @shaharnakash - See the CNContactFetchRequest sample provided. Please let me know if that works in your case?

Comment: C now its work, i use as you suggest         let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest( keysToFetch: keysToFetch)
and now all perfect :)

Comment: Hey Tommie! I just ran this code using my friend iPhone and we only get about 10% fo the entire contacts. Do you have any idea what would cause this? Or how can we receive the entire contact lists no matter the source?

Comment: @RoiMulia - I'm not sure when and where you are calling this code but just be aware that calling background threads in places like the window events can cause problems with competing threads used by Apple frameworks. I'd try calling the code from viewDidLoad or on some action but keep in mind the threading may give rise to race conditions. Also, make sure you use the unified contacts setting... Could be other things as well, I can't tell without more context. Let me know which if any of these suggestions help in your case.

Comment: Hey @TommieC. Thank you for replying so quickly. I'm running the code inside viewDidLoad function. I'm attaching the code snippet which i'm using: https://gist.github.com/roimulia/588be03804d9e97c0b157730e52bf516 When I run the code it gives me correct results. But on his iPhone I guess he logs in into iCloud and Gmail. Maybe this is the source of the issue. But I can't find a way to understand as I think my code is recommended by Apple. Do you see anything missing to fetch ALL of the user contacts?

Comment: Should I save CNContactStore in global memory or make it shared? Is there any need for that?

Comment: @Paresh.P - If you mean, should you store the variable at a global scope or not. I would put the information only within the scope where it is needed. I'd probably make it live just before the view where the contact list is generated. Would need more context with a code sample to make a better decision.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I was just asking to save memory that any global variable would acquire.

Answer (score 10):

Modified Tommie C's answer for XCode 8 & Swift 3.0.

```
func findContactsOnBackgroundThread ( completionHandler:@escaping (_ contacts:[CNContact]?)->()) {

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async(execute: { () -> Void in

        let keysToFetch = [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName),CNContactPhoneNumbersKey] as [Any] //CNContactIdentifierKey
        let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest( keysToFetch: keysToFetch as! [CNKeyDescriptor])
        var contacts = [CNContact]()
        CNContact.localizedString(forKey: CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone)

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            fetchRequest.mutableObjects = false
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        fetchRequest.unifyResults = true
        fetchRequest.sortOrder = .userDefault

        let contactStoreID = CNContactStore().defaultContainerIdentifier()
        print("\(contactStoreID)")


        do {

            try CNContactStore().enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest) { (contact, stop) -> Void in
                //do something with contact
                if contact.phoneNumbers.count > 0 {
                    contacts.append(contact)
                }

            }
        } catch let e as NSError {
            print(e.localizedDescription)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            completionHandler(contacts)

        })
    })
} 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    findContactsOnBackgroundThread { (contacts) in
            self.contactsList = contacts
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/// The default key descriptors to fetch
public var defaultFetchKeys: [String] = [CNContactGivenNameKey,
                                         CNContactFamilyNameKey,
                                         CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,
                                         CNContactImageDataAvailableKey,
                                         CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey]

/**
     Fetch contacts from the user's device

     - parameter sortOrder: The sort order that should be used. Default none.
     - returns: A list of contacts
     */
    public func fetchContacts(withSortOrder sortOrder: CNContactSortOrder = .givenName,
                              qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass = .background) -> Promise<[Contact]>
    {

        return Promise { seal in

            DispatchQueue.global(qos: qos).async {

                let store = CNContactStore()
                var contacts = [Contact]()

                /// A `PhoneNumberKit` object used to parse and format numbers (expensive!)
                let phoneNumberKit = PhoneNumberKit()

                let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: self.defaultFetchKeys as [CNKeyDescriptor])
                request.sortOrder = sortOrder
                request.unifyResults = true

                do {

                    try store.enumerateContacts(with: request) { contact, _ in

                        if let user = Contact(contact: contact, kit: phoneNumberKit) {
                            contacts.append(user)
                        }

                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        seal.fulfill(contacts)
                    }

                } catch {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        seal.reject(error)
                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }
```

I am also using `PhoneNumberKit` to standardise all numbers and `PromiseKit`, to chain my requests, but you can pretty much adjust it whatever you want it.